# Send email on Oracle Apex from different accounts

Tags: oracle-apex

I've configured on APEX_INSTANCE a email account, SMTP server, port etc.. it work fine calling the function send_mail of APEX.

Now I need send mail from different account, for example: sometime I need send from sales@example.com and another time from customer@example.com.

My question is:

Are there any way to specify the email account configuration on runtime?

I use Oracle Apex 19.

Comment: Koen already answered that APEX_MAIL.SEND has a parameter that specifies where you are sending from. But I wanted to add that sending from arbitrary emails will usually be stopped by the SMTP server. For same domain emails it should work, but if you try a foreign domain the smtp server might reject it if it is configured to do so as most are.

Comment: thank you for you reply 
I need change before to send the smtp parameters , but I dont know how I can change the parameter at run time or maybe change only for a oracle session.

Answer (score 0):

If you use apex_mail.send to send your emails, you can specify the account you are sending from for every email. There is parameter `p_from`. Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1//aeapi/APEX_MAIL.html#GUID-14F51C6D-CB82-4B38-AB6E-61C46E75596F).

In case you want to change the smtp settings at runtime, check [APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.SET_PARAMETER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/SET_PARAMETER-Procedure.html#GUID-A6D8CA93-798D-4582-97B9-C7D3ED709AC5).  I have not verified this, but the example in the docs indicates that it can be used to change email settings as well.

Comment: thank you for you reply 
Maybe I did not clearly explain my problem.
I want to change the SMTP settings. for example :
 smtp_host, smtp_port, smtp_user, smtp_password parameters at run time.
My idea is to have those data stored in a table and when sending the email take those values.

Comment: APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.SET_PARAMETER is only availble to run as SYSDBA user.  this  command change the  parameters is other way to access to "envirmoment sertting" page. Is a alternative to GUI configuration.

Comment: don't think there is

Answer (score 0):

```
declare

    v_INVONO VARCHAR2(20);
    V_TOTAL number;
    v_MOBILE varchar2(50);
    v_email varchar2(50);
    V_MST_ID NUMBER;
    v_body_html CLOB;
    v_add varchar2(500);
    v_city varchar2(100);
    v_order_lines clob;
    V_PAYMENT number;

begin

    select PHONE INTO v_MOBILE FROM CUSTOMER_INFO WHERE CUST_ID = :GLOBAL_CUSTOMER_ID;
    select EMAIL,address,city INTO v_email,v_add,v_city FROM APP_USERS WHERE upper(USERNAME) = upper(:APP_USER);

    select sum(c002*c003) into V_TOTAL from apex_collections c
    where c.collection_name = 'CUST_ORDER_ITEMS' and nvl(c003,0)>0;

    select lpad(nvl(max(to_number(INVONO))+1,1),6,0) into v_INVONO from SALES_MST;
    V_PAYMENT:=V_TOTAL-NVL(:discount_perc,0);

    INSERT INTO SALES_MST (
    INVONO, INVO_DATE, CUST_ID, 
    CUST_NAME, MOBILE, TOTAL, 
    DISCOUNT, SUB_TOTAL, PAYMENT, 
    DUE, USER_ID, ORDER_STATUS,ORDER_TIME, ORDER_EXPIRY_TIME) 

    VALUES
 ( v_INVONO,
    sysdate,
    :customer_id,
    :customer_name,
    v_MOBILE,
    V_TOTAL,
    :P13_DISC_PERC,
    V_TOTAL,
    V_TOTAL-NVL(:P13_DISC_PERC,0),
    null,
    null,'IP',SYSDATE, SYSDATE+((1/24)/60)*20 )
 RETURN ID,
 INVONO INTO V_MST_ID, 
:P10_ORDER_NO;

    v_body_html:='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Email Template email from apex </title>        
        <!-- Start Common CSS -->
        <style type="text/css">
            #outlook a {padding:0;}
            body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;}
            .ExternalClass {width:100%;}
            .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
            .backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}
            .main-temp table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;}
            .main-temp table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
        </style>
        <!-- End Common CSS -->
    </head>

    <body>

        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="backgroundTable main-temp" style="background-color: #d5d5d5;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidth" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                            <tbody>
                                <!-- Start header Section -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 30px;">
                                        <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee; text-align: center;">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <!--<td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                        <a href="https://htmlcodex.com"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="PapaChina" /></a>
                                                    </td>-->
                                                    <strong>organization name</strong>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        street 42 park line 
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        city, state, postal_code
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        Phone: 123-456-786 | Email: abc@abc.com
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 25px;">
                                                        <strong>Order Number:</strong> '||v_INVONO||' | <strong>Order Date:</strong> '||sysdate||'
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- End header Section -->
                                
                                <!-- Start address Section -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 0;">
                                        <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width: 55%; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                                        Delivery Adderss
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width: 45%; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                                        Billing Address
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width: 55%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        '||:customer_name||'
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width: 45%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        '||:customer_name||'
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width: 55%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        '||v_add||'
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width: 45%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        '||v_add||'
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width: 55%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        '||v_city||'
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width: 45%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        '||v_city||'
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- End address Section --> 
                                <!-- Start product Section -->';

    for i in (select c001,c002,c003,c004,c005 from apex_collections c
    where c.collection_name = 'CUST_ORDER_ITEMS' and nvl(c003,0)>0)
    loop
        INSERT INTO SALES_DTLS (
        INVONO, ID, DESCRIPTION, 
        UNIT, RATE, QTY,MST_ID) 
        VALUES ( v_INVONO,
        i.c001,
        i.c004,
        i.c005,
        i.c002,
        i.c003 ,V_MST_ID);
        v_order_lines := v_order_lines||
  '<tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 0;">
                                        <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;">

                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                                        '||i.c004||'
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575; width: 440px;">
                                                        Quantity: '||i.c003||'
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width: 130px;"></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575;">
                                                        
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575; text-align: right;">
                                                        Rs. '||i.c002||' Per Unit
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575; text-align: right; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                        <b style="color: #666666;">Rs. '||(i.c003*i.c002)||'</b> Total
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>

                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>';
    end loop;

    --v_order_lines := v_order_lines||'</table>';
    v_body_html:=v_body_html||v_order_lines||'<!-- End product Section -->
                                
                                <!-- Start calculation Section -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 0;">
                                        <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb; margin-top: -5px;">
                                            <tbody>
                                                                                             
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-top: 10px;">
                                                        Order Total
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-top: 10px; text-align: right;">
                                                        Rs. '||V_TOTAL||'
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                        Discount:
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; text-align: right;">
                                                        Rs. '||NVL(:P13_DISC_PERC,0)||'
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                        Payment Amount
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; text-align: right; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                        Rs. '||V_PAYMENT||'
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <!-- End calculation Section -->
                                
                                <!-- Start payment method Section -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 0 10px;">
                                        <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                                        Payment Method ('||:P12_PAYMENT_OPTION||')
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                
                                                <tr>

                                                    <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; font-style: italic; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; color: #666666; padding: 15px 0; border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;">
                                                        <b style="font-size: 14px;">Note:</b> 
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- End payment method Section -->
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>



</html>';

    :order_id := V_MST_ID;
    APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_COLLECTION(
    p_collection_name => 'CUST_ORDER_ITEMS');
    
    if :card_save = 'Y' then
        declare
            v_count number;

        begin

            select count(*) into v_count from CUSTOMER_CARDS where card_number=:card_number;
            if v_count = 0 then
                INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CARDS (
                CUST_ID, NAME_ON_CARD, 
                CARD_NUMBER, EXPIRY_DATE, CVC) 
                VALUES ( :customer_id,
                :card_name,
                :card_number ,
                :card_expiry,
                :card_cvc);
            else
                update CUSTOMER_CARDS set NAME_ON_CARD=:P12_NAME_ON_CARD,EXPIRY_DATE=:card_expiry,
                CVC=:card_cvc where card_number=:card_number;
            end if;
        end;

    END IF;

 IF  :yourcodeid IS NOT NULL THEN

    UPDATE CUSTOMER_VOUCHERS SET AVAILED='Y', AVAILED_DATE = SYSDATE
    WHERE VOUCHER_ID = :your_voucher_id and cust_id = :your_customer_id;
 
END IF;

 APEX_MAIL.SEND(

    p_to                        =>v_email,
    p_from                      =>'YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS',
    p_body                      =>null,
    p_body_html                 =>v_body_html,
    p_subj                      =>'Order ('||v_INVONO||') Confirmed!',
    p_cc                        => NULL,
    p_bcc                       =>NULL,
    p_replyto                   =>null
); 

    APEX_MAIL.PUSH_QUEUE;

END;
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.